# Codeigniter: error in base_url

Tags: codeigniter, base-url

i have one problem with function base_url() in my codeigniter.

I'm configure the condeigniter to:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'sistema_clientes/';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and autoload to:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

It's ok, but when i'm try to use base_url('clientes') in my pages, the link repeat.

example, i wanna this :  localhost/sistema_clientes/example.

```
<li><a href="<?= base_url('example'); ?>">Example</a></li>
```

in my url, the link go to: `http://localhost/sistema_clientes/sistema_clientes/clientes`

but i wanna this: `http://localhost/sistema_clientes/clientes`

i don't wanna the base_url() repeat the sistema_clientes, please help me.

what i can do to repear this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `base_url` like below:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sistema_clientes/';
```

Because `setting $config['base_url'] = 'sistema_clientes/';` makes sense that
you are going to `sistema_clientes` controller so base_url 
becomes`http://localhost/sistema_clientes/sistema_clientes`.

Comment: glad to help happy coding.